# ImageView centerCrop Overflow in CardView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-imageview, android-cardview

I doin' my daily practice. I saw this problem, the Image does not fit on Cardview.

I created a Cardview with wrap_Content Height,

**Looks like this,**

[image]

**The code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_gradient_hydroponic"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Types of Hydroponics"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="You can find out the various hydroponic systems, from how they work, the media needed and planting to making them."
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_myplants"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_navigate_next_24"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

And then, when I put my background image the `bg_card.png`. the problem started from here. I already set `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` There's a gap bottom there, you can see it.

**Here looks like,**

[image]

**The Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_gradient_hydroponic">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_card"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Types of Hydroponics"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="You can find out the various hydroponic systems, from how they work, the media needed and planting to making them."
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_myplants"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_navigate_next_24"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This is my Final Solution, i set my ImageView `android:layout_height="150dp"`

[image]

**The Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_gradient_hydroponic">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_card"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Types of Hydroponics"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="You can find out the various hydroponic systems, from how they work, the media needed and planting to making them."
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_myplants"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_navigate_next_24"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

So, How can I fit my ImageView with the CardView Height of the First one? (Image 1). I'm just curious.

Comment: **android:scaleType="fitXY"** use this line

Comment: Sorry bro, Still can't solve the gap problem :/ I already did it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's done!
I do trial and error, and here's what I got. It's the responsive view.
I'm dragging the id of Imageview to the height wrap_content layout.
It'll follow the height of wrap_content layout.

just use this on your ImageView  `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/height_card"`

**Here's an example:**

[image]

**Here's the code:**

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/height_card"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/shape_gradient_hydroponic" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/height_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Types of Hydroponics"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="You can find out the various hydroponic systems, from how they work, the media needed and planting to making them."
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_myplants"
                app:tint="#217373"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_navigate_next_24"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```